# How to build only single buildType with Android Studio and/or Gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I've several build types in my build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
  debug {
    storeFile file("debug.keystore")
    storePassword = "android"
    keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
    keyPassword = "android"
  }
  unsigned{
    storePassword = ""
    keyAlias = ""
    keyPassword = ""
  }
  release {
    storeFile file("release.keystore")
    keyAlias "alias"
    storePassword "foo"
    keyPassword "bar"
  }
}

buildTypes {
  release {
    debuggable false
    jniDebugBuild false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
  unsigned {
    debuggable false
    jniDebugBuild false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
  }
  debug {
    debuggable true
    jniDebugBuild true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
  }
}
```

which work fine but the problem is that I don't know (and I haven't find after lot of searching) a way how to build only single build type either from Android Studio or command-line.

Do you please know?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Documentation says (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Building-and-Tasks) that you can use the following commands to produce specific build types:

```
gradle assembleDebug
gradle assembleRelease
```

Comment: For anyone who looking for TeamCity task: `gradlew clean assembleDebug check` will 1) clean output folder 2) build app-debug.apk 3) run tests